# How to align PVC pipe to metal electrical box

Tags: electrical

I'm transitioning outdoor PVC conduit through the rim joist and into a metal box. The problem is that my holes in the box don't quite line up with where my conduit comes in. Is there an easy way to adjust the alignment or a type of box that is maneuverable to line up with the conduit? The location is through the rim joist and the box is between the floor joists.

Comment: A picture possibly?

Comment: How are you planning to attach the conduit to the box?

Comment: Threaded adapter through the box hole

Comment: I think by switching box styles, I can just put a 2x4 between the joists and attach it to that at any horizontal and vertical position I want. That's my best solution so far

Answer (score 3):

You can make a transition with a piece of carflex (LFNC) or sealtite (LFMC) to make a flexible offset in your conduit. Use a PVC male adapter and a sealtite connector to make the transition. Some hardware stores will already have small piece of flex premanufactured. The only problems with this is sometimes this can look pretty ugly, and pulling through may get a little tougher. Be sure and bring along some pulling lubricant to help.

Good luck.

Comment: @Joe, if you need the flexibility of being able to manipulate the end an unpredictable amount, flex is a great idea.  If you can measure how much offset you need, a simpler solution would be just to bend the conduit.  PVC bends easily when it's hot.  You can keep it from collapsing by filling the bend area with hot sand.  Then use a heat gun on the outside.  Put in a small bend and a short distance later, a small bend back to create the offset you need.  That avoids the extra joints and the ridges you need to pull past.

Comment: If the bends are minor or gradual, they shouldn't interfere with getting them through the holes.  If that's a problem, enlarge the holes slightly or feed from the other direction.  If you have the space at the box, do the bending in place.